# Are PHP Closure Objects eligible for garbage collection

Tags: php, garbage-collection, closures

I was wondering if anyone knows if PHP's anonymous functions are eligible for garbage collection?

I know that functions created with `create_function` are not garbage collected but I haven't been able to find any reference about ones created with the `function(){}` syntax (internally represented as a Closure object).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PHP's garbage collector does not discriminate between types of "things" - if it has at least one reference somewhere, it is kept. The moment this does not apply, the resource is garbage-collected.

This is **not** the same as using `create_function`, as PHP throws the create_function reference in the global scope in addition to referencing it. A closure (a Closure object, if you prefer, as this is what they are!) only exists in the scope it was created in + all the ones you pass it to.

If you want to convince yourself of it, run this little piece of code:

```
<?php
$r = memory_get_usage();
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $k = function() {echo "boo"; };
    if (memory_get_usage() > $r) {
            echo "Different memory count. Off by: ".(memory_get_usage() -$r);
    }
    $r = memory_get_usage();
}
```

You will get exactly one echo. Replace the `$k` assignment with create_function, and you'll get 100.

Comment: good description. since it is an object I figured it must fall out of scope and php would do the right thing.

Comment: @Orangepill: PHP does not always do the right thing, sadly. Point remains, `create_function` = `eval`.

Comment: I'm currently looking for a way to nix `create_function` from a project I'm working on but I'm not seeing any way around it. Would appreciate any guidance you could give http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/26268/potential-problems-with-this-templating-technique

Comment: @Orangepill: store a closure instead of create_function. When it is called, ob_start before it, ob_get_clean after it. Done, and as an added benefit, unset the partial and the memory is also freed.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this, by the way. It makes PHP remote code execution trivial.

Comment: I can nix non-file system paths and I think I will build that into the architecture, but if I include it in a buffer it's going to resolve the variables and code at the time of inclusion and if I get it as a string I'm still going to have to eval it.

Comment: @Orangepill: eval it inside the closure? Means you've got a bit of overhead in terms of memory, but not as much as create_function as the reference to the string is inside the closure. Still, is your template stuff needing to be that dynamic for you to **have** to use `eval`? What's wrong with writing PHP code and just including?

Comment: On the contrary the templates are likely to be pretty simple what the template processor is trying to solve is iterative filesystem hits on i/o bound servers. A template wouldn't be for a page but row in a table that going to be included 1000 times. Initial performance tests are running 7.5x as fast as include with almost half the memory consumption.

Comment: @Orangepill: your best bet for the solution is **caching** (RAM through redis/memcached), not `eval`. Don't kill a fly with a bazooka.

Answer (score 0):

You can see by xdebug_debug_zval( 'a' ); if xdebug is installed. http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php

Comment: Off-topic and faulty reasoning: in everything but the simplest case, the method suggested can lead to erroneous deductions. A memory leak in the test case would lead to the wrong conclusion.